# how to declare a variable as global for all methods of a class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using MYSQL PDO for MYSQL queries and i have stored database connection in the variable $db.
While using PDO queries in methods of a class i have to declare $db as global variable in each class.
Is there a way i can declare it as global at once and it works for all methods?
Following is what i am doing :

```
 <?php
    class example {
    method 1 {
    global $db;
    other statements
    }
    method 2 {
    global $db;
    other statements
     }
    }
    ?>
```

And following code also didn't worked.

```
 <?php
    class example {
    global $db;
    method 1 {
    statements
    }
    method 2 {
    statements
     }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest doing it like this

```
<?php
class example {
  protected $db;

  public function __construct(name\space\DB $db) {
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  public function method1() {
    $this->db->query()...
  }

  public function method2() {
    $this->db->query()...
  }
}
?>
```

Passing the DB class to other classes like this is called Dependency Injection. It's a common and good convention to follow. I'd highly recommend reading up on it if you're unsure what it means.

After passing in the DB class I can just register it as a property inside the scope of class example. Then all methods inside this class will have it available.

Comment: Yes, this is the way, I was just about to write it down. :-)

Comment: ok thanks ,
And i am instantiating the same class in method 2 and i am calling method 1.Is there  any better way to call method 1 of same class in method 2?

Comment: @BrainyPrb: $this->methodName() refers to a method in the same class. When inside a class $this refers to the class itself. You have access to all properties and mtehods through this scope.